# Rotate out - meaning

Tags: meaning

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/ukraine-army-deflated-guerrilla-warfare-unfolds-170833583.html

> And acting Defense Minister Mykhailo Koval likely further soured moods by announcing Thursday that no troops involved in operations in east Ukraine would be **rotated out** as there is not enough personnel.

What does **rotate out** mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One sense of rotate is "to replace (a person, troops, etc.) by another or others, usually according to a schedule or plan." (dictionary.com)

The idea here is that troops need substantial amounts of time off after a certain amount of active duty, but there aren't any to replace the ones in question, so the original troops will need to stay on duty longer than expected.